# eval inside onreadystatechange doesn't works

Tags: javascript, eval

I have one http request:

```
var System = {
    startApp:function(package) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET","/@APP:/" + package + "/manifest.xml");
        xhttp.send();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                eval("(" + package + ".onCreate())"); //THE ERROR IS HERE
            }
        };
    };
};
```

But when i call:

```
var a = new System.startApp("b.c");
var b;
b.c.onCreate = function() {
    document.writeln("function called!!");
};
```

It doesn't works and I'm running the code in Android's Chrome Canary, so I can't get the console prompt because I dont have Desktop.

Comment: I dont have desktop.

Comment: Im asking from my Android in Brazil and i run the code using AIDE Web

Comment: For this, I need a desktop, and i dont have a desktop

Comment: @EduardoProcópioGomez — Get one. You can't crowd source all your trivial debugging.

Comment: So how i can use ```package + "onCreate()"```?

Comment: Heh, in Brazil this doesn't exists

Comment: I will try.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191379/discussion-between-c1moore-and-eduardo-procopio-gomez).

Comment: Sorry for the time! Doesn't work

Comment: are you sure your use of 'this' is correct in this context ? I think it should be xhttp

Comment: Yes, its correct